# Qt "Form Load" function

Tags: c++, qt

i created new form in Qt and i would like to ask you where is form load function, where i can put my code.

And another problems are that file_exists doesn't work and i dont know why (i would like to use C native functions), and my Messagebox show before form load why? I would like to load while form and then show my Messagebox. And the last thing is that this->close(); at if statement doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
#include "nacitanie_okno.h"
#include "ui_nacitanie_okno.h"
#include "funkcie.h"
#include <iostream>

const char *subory[] = { "test.txt" } ;

nacitanie_okno::nacitanie_okno(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::nacitanie_okno)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    int i;
    int pocet = 1;

    int percent = 20 / pocet;
    for(i = 0; i < pocet ; i++){

        if(file_exists(subory[i])){
            ui->progressBar->setValue(ui->progressBar->value() + percent);
        } else {
            MessageBox("Hi","teeest"); // my own function for messagebox
            this->close();
        }
    }

}

nacitanie_okno::~nacitanie_okno()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

and in funkcie.h is this:

```
bool file_exists(const char * subor)
{
    if (FILE * sub = fopen(subor, "r"))
    {
        fclose(sub);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. The best way to create Form is pointers .
   The "Load Form" function is the constructor of the class .
   So when you want to create a form ,lets say you have "class Myform;" which is a gui form class, should be like this :

   Myform* form = new Myform("constructor variables");

   This will call the constructor where there you should write what you want as Form Load Function .
2. use this->hide this should work .
3. Print errno value , as fopen sets the errno value upon error .

Comment: 1. I have Qt Form Class its named "nacitanie_okno" and i have nacitanie_okno.cpp, nacitanie_okno.h and nacitanie_okno.ui.. i just clicked to my project and selected Add --> Qt --> Qt Designer Form Class and i cant see any form load.

2. this->hide(); doesn't work